# A way to get vlookup in Excel file to search for csv.file in set directory using cell value then returna given cell value from csv file?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Basically want to go to different drive (D), search with cell A1 for .csv file that will have be called A1.csv (e.g. if A1 is 10020, file will be 10020.csv). The sheet should have same name as file name.

I then want the formula to return cell value A3 from CSV file

`=VLOOKUP(A1,'\\D\[A1.csv]A1'!F3,3,FALSE)`

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do this. An ".csv" file doesn't have columns or rows as in excel, rather is position is determined by a delimiter position. You need to convert the ".csv" file to an excel file (.xlsx) to be able to do a vlookup.

Comment: Also I would think you can't use complex formulas for closed workbooks.